# MySQL CURDATE com mês

Tags: mysql

Em MySQL se eu quero buscar apenas datas que estejam no ano atual, faço assim:

```
WHERE dia = year(CURDATE())
```

Mas fui tentar buscar datas que estejam no mesmo mês que o atual assim:

```
WHERE dia = month(CURDATE())
```

e não aceita, retorna vazio, mesmo tendo datas no mês atual cadastrado, como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa da função `MONTH` dos dois lados. O mesmo vale pra função `YEAR` que você está usando.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tabela
WHERE
  MONTH(tabela.data) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
  YEAR(tabela.data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Lembrando que usando o filtro de mês sem o filtro de ano, você vai acabar com registros de anos anteriores que sejam do mês de maio, por exemplo. Combine o filtro de mês com o filtro de ano como acima.